# SQL Server 2008 Fetch modified values between dates

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, pivot-table

```
Modified   FirstName LastName PassportNumber
2014-09-03 Eric      Clifton  J12345
2014-09-04 Mathew    NULL     NULL
2014-09-05 Adams     Thomas   NULL
2014-09-06 Steve     NULL     H09090
```

When Query between dates 2014-09-03 and 2014-09-06, output should be:

```
FirstName LastName PassportNumber
Steve     Thomas   H090909
```

When Query between dates 2014-09-03 and 2014-09-05, output should be:

```
FirstName LastName PassportNumber
Adams     Thomas   J12345
```

When Query between dates 2014-09-04 and 2014-09-04, output should be:

```
FirstName LastName PassportNumber
Mathew    NULL     NULL
```

In summary, updated changed values till date entered - From and To date should be displayed.
If any change is not done between given date range, NULL should be displayed.
Please help how can i achieve this?

Thanks,
Avni Bhatt

Answer (score 0):

I am still unclear with your Question:

The below Queries will be useful to get the output as shown in your Examples:

```
select top 1 FirstName, LastName, PassportNumber, Modified
from table_name
where Modified between '2014-09-03' and '2014-09-06'
order by Modified desc
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.The query you suggested will fetch an entrire first row which matched the condition. I need to get values which are changed between given dates.